# Permutations with fixed points

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am trying to write a java program that counts permutations of a string, I would like to check my results by hand, but I can remember (or find) the formula to count the number of permutations, and the number of permutations with a set number of fixed points.

For instance, I know that the string ABC

With 0 fixed points

ABC BAC CAB ACB BCA CBA - 6 permutations

With 1 fixed points (not sure if I did it right)

ABC CBA ACB BCA - 6 permutations

... and so on

So my question, what is the formula to find the number of permutations with fixed points. And if you could give a simple example.

Thank you!!

- exactly k fixed numbers

Comment: What do you mean by fixed points?

Comment: 3 different symbols (A,B,C), so 3! = 3x2x1 = 6 different permutations.  With A "fixed" at position 1, then you have 2 different symbols (B,C), so 2! = 2x1 = 2 different permutations.

Comment: Are you assuming that none of the other $n - k$ objects are in their original positions?

Comment: You want the so-called recontres numbers [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers].